# nodejs - filter live output

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I'm trying to narrow down the live output of this nodejs script.

```
var autobahn = require('autobahn');
var wsuri = "wss://api.poloniex.com";
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
  url: wsuri,
  realm: "realm1"
});

connection.onopen = function (session) {
        function marketEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        function tickerEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        function trollboxEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        session.subscribe('BTC_XMR', marketEvent);
        session.subscribe('ticker', tickerEvent);
        session.subscribe('trollbox', trollboxEvent);
}

connection.onclose = function () {
  console.log("Websocket connection closed");
}

connection.open();
```

The script is taken from an API documentation of an exchange:
https://poloniex.com/support/api/

When I run it in node, I get live updates of all currency pairs. How do I output only a selected pair?

I could not see anything like that in the documentation.

Comment: What pair(s) do you want?

Comment: I'd like BTC_SDC. Thank you.

Comment: What about changing `session.subscribe('BTC_XMR', marketEvent);` to `session.subscribe('BTC_SDC', marketEvent);`? I currently don't have access to a node environment, so have no idea what the output even looks like :P

Comment: This event shows transactions between BTC and XMR. I since have commented it out. The event that displays all of them is TickerEvent. The third event can also be commented out - it's the chat from that website

Comment: So it would have to be done in TickerEvent.

Comment: Is passsing it through an external CLI like `grep` an option?

Comment: I'd rather not use any grep/sed tools - as I'd like to capture particular values for the pair and use them further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function tickerEvent (args,kwargs) {
        if(args[0] !== "BTC_SDC"){
            return; // causes anything not "BTC_SDC" related to be filtered out.
        }
        console.log(args); // information you want.
     }
```

I suggest casing on the first item of that array in ticker.

Comment: Brilliant - that's it. What do you mean 'casing on the first item'?

Comment: Use a `switch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

instead of writting else if else if else if repeatedly to get more information and do different things in those "cases". The API is also sending back a very badly shaped payload I would recommend mapping it out to an object so its easier to understand and you arent using "magic numbers" to know the order of things in that array.